# Refresh a page using LUA

Tags: lua, openresty

I have a back-end on LUA openresty. And I need to refresh a page like 
in php-code:

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

How to do the same in LUA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
page = [[
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">
</head>
]]
ngx.say(page)
```